# Scala : retrieve mutliple values from a url

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to the Scala world and the Play Framework. In my scala model i'm able to get values from a url based on a GET method. Some values come from a single select and others from a multiple select. For the single select i know how to retrieve the single value, but how to retrieve the values from the multiple select ? :

My url looks like this : `?authorId=1&booksId=1,4,6&section=1`

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) }
```

Then i retrieve the values and fetch them in a database :

...

```
(c.authorId === params.get("authorId ").?) and //from a single select : it works
(c.booksId in params.get("booksId").?) and // from a multiple select : i dont know how since i cannot use a string !
```

**params.get("booksId")** contains my list of **ids = 1,4,6**

How can i fetch the booksId in my dataBase using the **in** statement ?

PS : I'm using Squeryl

Thanks

Comment: Are you using slick? did you simply try using in instead of select?

Comment: I'm using squeryl. I tried : (c.booksId in  params.get("booksId").toString.split(",").toList) but didn't work :(

Comment: I logged the output of the booksId params and i got : Some(1,4,6), maybe that's why i didnt work ?

Answer (score 1):

`params.get` returns an `Option[String]`, so you can't call String methods directly on the result of `params.get("booksId")`. Instead, you need to map on the Option:

```
params.get("booksId").map { booksId =>
  val bookIds = booksId.split(",").toList
  c.booksId in bookIds
}
```

This will return an Option[WhateverSquerylReturns]. To get the value of the Option if it's defined, see Option.getOrElse.

Comment: That's a good start msiebert but i cannot use your syntax inside my query since it says :  Type mismatch, expected: logicalBoolean, acutal : Option[InclusionOperator]  : c.authorId === params.get("authorId ").?) and ( params.get("booksId").map { booksId => val bookIds = booksId.split(",").toList c.booksId in bookIds })

Comment: You should move your authorId query logic into the body of the map as well.